# How to use pass database name into stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a database where I keep all my stored procedures and functions called `'utils'` These objects should be able to be called from other databases.

This is the stored procedure I am having issues with

```
USE [Utils]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_trim_all_string_columns]    Script Date: 13/12/2016 10:54:30 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_trim_all_string_columns] @DatabaseName Varchar(100), @SchemaName Varchar(100),@TableName Varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL + ',[', '[') +
              COLUMN_NAME + ']=LTRIM(RTRIM([' + COLUMN_NAME + ']))'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName AND TABLE_NAME = @TableName AND DATA_TYPE Like '%char%'

SET @SQL = 'UPDATE [' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @TableName + '] SET ' + @SQL

EXEC (@SQL)

END
```

There is a line in the code that always fails

```
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

The reason is that the sp belongs to the `utils` database so only finds the columns that exists in the `utils` schema. I need to be able to parameterize that line so I can pass in the database name like so

```
FROM MYDATABASE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

I tried to use

```
FROM @DatabaseName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

but that fails as `@DatabaseName` is just a string

Any help people?

Comment: Sorry totalitarian.  SQL Server doesn't allow you to pass identifiers, like database and table names, as variables.  What you can do is build and then execute [dynamic SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  Or you could follow @IvanStarostin's advice, and place a copy of the SP in every database.  Of the two approaches I prefer the latter, but without knowing more about your setup it is hard to recommend one approach over the other.

Answer (score 1):

Spread this SP to all DBs, then:

```
exec master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; exec usp_trim_all_string_columns;'
```

or rewrite it to completely dynamic sql with DB defined insed dynamic sql.

Comment: Would I have to run that command every time I create a new database?

Comment: I don't get it. You'd have to run it when you think you have to.

Comment: you also can ignore system databases